# Updating list based on Bool - SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to create a checklist view with a list of items decoded from a .json where upon tapping the item it marks it as completed. What I am struggling on is making the list update as you mark items as completed. At the moment it will only update after closing the view then opening it again.

Here is the view:

```swift
struct ChecklistView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @ObservedObject var checkList: Checklist
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text(checkList.checklist)
                    .font(.title)
                Spacer()
                Button("Close") {
                    presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                }
            }
            List(checkList.actions, id: \.id) { item in
                if item.action == "" {
                    Text(item.name).italic()
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        .font(.callout)
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                } else {
                    Button(action: {
                        item.completed.toggle()
                    }) {
                        if item.completed {
                            HStack {
                                Image(systemName: "checkmark.square")
                                    .foregroundColor(.green)
                                Text(item.name)
                                Spacer()
                                Text(item.action)
                                    .font(.caption)
                                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                            }
                        } else {
                            HStack {
                                Image(systemName: "square")
                                Text(item.name)
                                Spacer()
                                Text(item.action)
                                    .font(.caption)
                                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }.padding()
    }
}
```

Here is the class for the checklist:

```swift
class Checklist: Codable, Identifiable, ObservableObject {
    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case checklist
        case actions
    }
    var id = UUID()
    var checklist: String
    var actions: [Action]
    
    class Action: Codable, Identifiable, ObservableObject {
        enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
            case name
            case action
        }
        var id = UUID()
        var name: String
        var action: String
        @Published var completed: Bool = false
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Action instance is not observed by SwiftUI.

When changing the status of the Action, no change is registered by the Checklist instance, so no event is published in the `objectWillChangePublisher` of the `Checklist`.

To get the view for the item to update, you have to store the item as an `@ObservedObject` somewhere. This can be accomplished by wrapping the UI elements for the list item in a separate view:

```swift
struct ActionView: View {
    @ObservedObject var action: Checklist.Action

    init(action: Checklist.Action) {
        self.action = action
    }

    var body: some View {
        ...
    }
}
```

Alternatively, make `Action` a struct, make `var actions` `@Published` and change the action on the checklist instance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `Checklist` class -- you have it set to be an @ObservableObject, but you don't have an observable properties on it (ie @Published).  Instead, you have an array of `Action`s which are also classes, which publish a `completed` property.  But, your `List` doesn't see that, because it's just watching a static `actions` property on checklist.

I'd suggest turning your `Action`s into structs and making the `actions` are @Published.

```
class Checklist: Identifiable, ObservableObject {
    var id = UUID()
    var checklist: String = ""
    @Published var actions: [Action] = []
    
    struct Action: Identifiable {
        enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
            case name
            case action
        }
        var id = UUID()
        var name: String
        var action: String
        var completed: Bool = false
    }
}
```

There are caveats.  One is that your logic for checking an item is going to get a little more complex.  One possibility:

```
checkList.actions = checkList.actions.map {
                            if $0.id == item.id {
                                var updatedItem = item
                                updatedItem.completed.toggle()
                                return updatedItem
                            }
                            return $0
                        }
```

Another is that having the @Published property on Checklist is going to break `Codable` initially.  Lots of possibilities for this including storing `Checklist` itself in a different wrapper, doing more manual decoding, etc.

So, still some decisions to be made, but this should get you started.